# Lookup cognito userpool uset based on cognito dentity pool identity in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I am an AWS newb, so please go easy on me :) 
I have setup a proof of concept to proove out an authenticated API backed by lambda with the following components.

API Gateway -> backed by Lambda
Federated Identities backed by AWS Cognito UserPool
I have the authorizer setup in the API gateway to use the IAM role which is being provided by the Federated Identity pool.

I can see the identity (`ap-southeast-2:<GUID>`) coming through into the gateway ( using this in my integration request mapping template `"$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId"` ) from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference

From either the gateway or lambda how can I resolve the `'ap-southeast-2:<GUID>'` back to the source identity which resides in the user pool. (E.g. Pull one of the custom attributes from it)

Other information if relevant, i'm using Amplify-AWS for the client calling into the API Gateway.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're noticing, Cognito as an identity provider is not the same as Cognito as a user pool.

- Federated Identities provide a way of giving someone identified access to your AWS resources. The `identity_id` the identity provider gives you can almost be thought of as a tracking code. CIP (Congito [Federated] Identity Provider) allows you to get an identity id by signing in through any number of providers (not just the user pool), and even by not signing in at all.
- User Pools give you a way of managing users for your application (i.e. a set of usernames, emails, passwords, etc).

This is the reason getting from `identity_id` back to the user pool user is hard (because, there's no guarantee it *is* a user pool user, it could well be someone from Facebook).

From what you've said, however, the assumption that said `identity_id` came from a UserPool authentication is safe. This means you have two options:

The **official** way will be to use [identity:GetOpenIdToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdToken.html) to convert `identity_id` (you can ignore the `logins` part of the request) into an OpenId token. You can then use this token against the [userpools:GetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html) end point. There's a few pitfalls here, like ensuring you authenticate with a scope that allows you to see all the attributes you care about.

Curiously, however, the value of `cognitoAuthenticationProvider` is not opaque, and can (unoffically) be decoded:

```
  // Cognito authentication provider looks like:
  // cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx,cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_aaaaaaaaa:CognitoSignIn:qqqqqqqq-1111-2222-3333-rrrrrrrrrrrr
  // Where us-east-1_aaaaaaaaa is the User Pool id
  // And qqqqqqqq-1111-2222-3333-rrrrrrrrrrrr is the User Pool User Id
```

The above example, with more details about how you can then use this with [userpools:AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) can be found here: https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/mapping-cognito-identity-id-and-user-pool-id.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @thomasmichaelwallace. This has made me ask the question about why am i even using federated identity, when i can fall back to the access token generated from the user pool and have a UserPool authenticator to secure the api gateway.

Comment: We've just rolled out cognito on our own stuff and I ended up only using UserPools.